# How to generate strings by regexp in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Suppose there is a simple regular expression (only | and * are allowed). How would you create a stream of strings of any size (from smaller to larger) which match this regular expression in Scala?

Comment: * means zero or more, but more of what? | means OR. You need at least a . to match each character, or specific characters too.

Comment: yes, specific chars are allowed: e.g. a, b (with * and |)

Answer (score 4):

Use [Xeger](http://code.google.com/p/xeger/). Even though it's Java and not Scala, you should have no problem using it with Scala.

In Java:

```
String regex = "[ab]{4,6}c";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
assert result.matches(regex);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like `(only | and * are allowed)`.

Comment: Note that a [fork](https://github.com/bluezio/xeger) of the original repo which is maintained to some degree as of late 2020 is available.